# Same command giving different output

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute command:

```
ps -e|grep some-process-name|grep -v grep|awk '{print $1}'|grep -v $$
```

And it gives me the pid of process with process name: "some-process-name"

But when I use the same long command in the shell script, with process name being passed as command line argument and used through "$1" I get two pids in the output.

```
PIDS=$(ps -e|grep $1|grep -v grep|awk '{print $1}'|grep -v $$)
echo $PIDS
```

What can be the reason for this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i do not see this behaviour on bash 4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.
is pgrep available on your platform? 
*pgrep some-process-name* should do the trick for you.